# What sort of sorted datastructure is optimized for finding items within a range?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, theory

Say I have a bunch of objects with dates and I regularly want to find all the objects that fall between two arbitrary dates.  What sort of datastructure would be good for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A binary search tree sounds like what you're looking for.
You can use it to find all the objects in O(log(N) + K), where N is the total number of objects and K is the number of objects that are actually in that range. (provided that it's balanced). Insertion/removal is O(log(N)).

Most languages have a built-in implementation of this.

- C++:
  http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/set/
- Java:
  http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html

You can find the lower bound of the range (in log(n)) and then iterate from there until you reach the upper bound.

Comment: The OP would want to use a multimap (or a multiset) instead

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you mean by date when you say sorted, an array will do it.

Do a binary search to find the index that's >= the start date. You can then either do another search to find the index that's <= the end date leaving you with an offset & count of items, or if you're going to process them anyway just iterate though the list until you exceed the end date.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to give a good answer without a little more detail.

What kind of performance do you need?

If linear is fine then I would just use a list of dates and iterate through the list collecting all dates that fall within the range. As **Andrew Grant** suggested.

Do you have duplicates in the list?

If you need to have repeated dates in your collection then most implementations of a binary tree would probably be out. Something like Java's TreeSet are set implementations and don't allow repeated elements.

What are the access characteristics? Lots of lookups with few updates, vice-versa, or fairly even?

Most datastructures have trade-offs between lookups and updates. If you're doing lots of updates then some datastructure that are optimized for lookups won't be so great.

So what are the access characteristics of the data structure, what kind of performance do you need, and what are structural characteristics that it must support (e.g. must allow repeated elements)?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to make random-access modifications: a tree, as in v3's answer. Find the bottom of the range by lookup, then count upwards. Inserting or deleting a node is O(log N). stbuton makes a good point that if you want to allow duplicates (as seems plausible for datestamped events), then you don't want a tree-based set.

If you do not need to make random-access modifications: a sorted array (or vector or whatever). Find the location of the start of the range by binary chop, then count upwards. Inserting or deleting is O(N) in the middle. Duplicates are easy.

Algorithmic performance of lookups is the same in both cases, O(M + log N), where M is the size of the range. But the array uses less memory per entry, and *might* be faster to count through the range, because after the binary chop it's just forward sequential memory access rather than following pointers.

In both cases you can arrange for insertion at the end to be (amortised) O(1). For the tree, keep a record of the end element at the head, and you get an O(1) bound. For the array, grow it exponentially and you get amortised O(1). This is useful if the changes you make are always or almost-always "add a new event with the current time", since time is (you'd hope) a non-decreasing quantity. If you're using system time then of course you'd have to check, to avoid accidents when the clock resets backwards.

Alternative answer: an SQL table, and let the database optimise how it wants. And Google's BigTable structure is specifically designed to make queries fast, by ensuring that the result of any query is always a consecutive sequence from a pre-prepared index :-)

Answer (score -1):

You want a structure that keeps your objects sorted by date, whenever you insert or remove a new one, and where finding the boundary for the segment of all objects later than or earlier than a given date is easy.

A [heap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_(data_structure)) seems the perfect candidate. In practical applications, heaps are simply represented by an array, where all the objects are stored in order. Seeing that sorted array as a heap is simply a way to make insertions of new objects and deletions happen in the right place, and in O(log(n)).

When you have to find all the objects between date A (excluded) and B (included), find the position of A (or the *insert* position, that is, the position of the earlier element later than A), and the position of B (or the insert position of B), and return all the objects between those positions (which is simply the section between those positions in the array/heap)

Comment: In the context of a heap, how do you return "the objects between those positions"? E.g from the image in the link you posted, how would you return nodes with values from [0..4] ?